# Speed up access to certain files

Tags: windows, memory, virtualization

I have a few files on my hard drive that are used by certain application very frequently, it just reads them randomly during the work.

Since the HDD is quite slow, an application is experiencing some sort of lags. I want to improve the performance by utilizing some sort of RAM drive, the idea is to physically place those frequently accessed files into RAM.

The problem is that I cannot just move those files into RAM and change the location paths for my application, I need to find a way to "virtualize" those files so the application could access them "by reference".

It must be some sort of a "shortcut" but more low-level I think, so an application will not be able to find a difference.

Is there some soft for this? Can anybody direct me? I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and can be made with the mklink utility. It'll only work on windows vista or 7

Comment: Or any Unix-like system

Comment: Yup. I was meaning "only" with reference to windows - it won't work on 2K or XP ;p

Comment: Apologies, but I am not seeing how using a symbolic link would improve the performance. (Just curious how it would work.)

Comment: Not directly - he wants to move commonly used files over to a ramdisk, but with the logical locations still on the physical drive. The *only* way to do a cross drive link on windows is symbolic links. Whether that actually improves his performance is an exercise left to the OP ;p